# Get Rid of Black Background Cherry Tree

Tags: tree, background-color

Im using linux OS and running Version 0.99.40

I dont know, but my cherry tree background suddenly changes to black:

[image: Complete Black Background instead of light blue]

My Background Color should be like this:

[image]

Things i tried:

- Removing cherrytree/config.cfg
- Uninstall then Reinstall
- Prefences
- Google

---

I just want to change color back to normal...

Sorry I cant find tags named 'cherrytree' etc

Answer (score 0):

The click order is:
File -> Preferences -> Preferences -> Theme